# Spring Boot (Legacy) with GAE - Autowiring

Tags: java, spring, maven, google-app-engine, spring-boot

I'm trying to make spring-boot-legacy:1.0.1.RELEASE & spring-boot-starter-parent:1.1.8.RELEASE with GAE 1.9.19. However, upon running via mvn appengine:devserver, I get the following error that prevents the app from running:

```
[INFO] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.reflect.Parameter is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:52)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.core.StandardReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(StandardReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer.java:53)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.core.PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.java:65)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:182)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1115)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
```

From what I understand, Spring uses reflection to auto-wire dependencies but it seems certain classes in the java.lang.reflect package are restricted. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: try to run your app under java 1.7

Comment: silly me. I forgot to change my JAVA_HOME to a java 7 sdk.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`java.lang.reflect.Parameter` is used by Spring under Java 8. So you have to downgrade to Java 7 to avoid it. Another reason for this is that Google Appengine doesn't have support for Java 8, only Java 7. So you need it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

check the migration guide 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/migrating-to-java8

add add `<runtime>java8</runtime>` to appengine-web.xml